# Find & Replace Textboxes and Macros

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

Is there a way to find and replace embedded macros in textboxes?

Example. I create a lot of textboxes and I assign them macro's say RunBox.1 WalkBox.1 SleepBox.1 now lets say I copy those textboxes. It will have the macro's I assigned in the box earlier in it and I'd like to change .1 to .2

```
Dim tb As TextBox
Dim actionName As String 

Sub AAA()    
    For Each tb In ActiveSheet.TextBoxes
        actionName = tb.OnAction
        actionName = Replace(actionName, "CGSF", "KBTUGSF")
        tb.OnAction = actionName Next 
End Sub
```

This isn't working not quite sure what I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the textbox's `OnAction` property.

```
Dim tb as TextBox
Dim actionName as String

For Each tb In ActiveSheet.TextBoxes
    actionName = tb.OnAction
    actionName = Replace(actionName, ".1", ".2")
    tb.OnAction = actionName
Next
```

Comment: This is giving me a Run-Time Error 1004 Unable to set the OnAction property of the TextBox class

Comment: For reference this is one of their Range Names TextBox 80

Comment: Is `RunBox.1 WalkBox.1` names of the TextBoxes, or names of the *procedure/macro* assigned to the textboxes?

Comment: and what does a Range Name have to do with any of this?

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to find out is what you're actually trying to change? The textbox's `.Name` can be changed the same way, just use `.Name` instead of `.onAction`.

Comment: The macro's assigned to the textboxes

Comment: I guess it doesn't have much to do with it, although it is the name of the textbox. Mostly was pointing that out to verify it was a textbox

Comment: any chance the sheet is maybe protected? When I test this, it works exactly as I'd expect. I can even give the `onAction` property a named macro that doesn't exist (of course it will error whenyou click it, but you can still assign an invalid named macro).

Comment: I opened a new Excel file and created a new Text box and it works. Thanks!